# "Something that work" or "something that works"?

Tags: phrases, verbs

Googling both sentences I find many references with or without *-s*. Should I add the *-s* to the verb after "that"? Is it considered a third person singular?

I'm searching for a rule to apply to the verb after "that".

Another example could be this:

> people that work (56,100,000 hits)
>   people that works (710,000 hits)

Comment: Interesting question. I just googled the two phrases too. 20% use "Something that work", 80% use "Something that works"

Comment: That's an interesting question. "Something that works" sounds correct, but as a native italian speaker I would never use the indicative present in such a case, but rather a subjunctive which, as I understand, is identical to the infinitive in English (i.e. no -s for the third person singular).

Comment: @kemp: context is important here. The subjunctive is used in limited circumstances in English, so in the absence of any additional information, assume it's indicative, and add the "s".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In *English Grammar* (ISBN 0-06-467109-7), *something* is listed in the indefinite pronouns always used as singular, together with *somebody*, *someone*, *each*, *either*, *everybody*, *anyone*, etc.

The correct phrase is *something that works.*

Comment: Nice, "something that work" is just a common mistake then. I'm wondering why so many people make that mistake as "something" is obviously singular.

Answer (score 5):

> Googling both sentences i find a lot of references with or without -s.

I didn't expect to find this, but you are right:

```
"something that work"     159,000 hits
"something that works" 38,500,000  hits
```

This is the weakness of Googling, that wrong stuff, if repeated often enough, starts to look legitimate. The correct one is "something that works".

> Is it considered as third person singular?

A verb after "something" should be in the third person singular form, yes.

Comment: Another weakness of using Google in this way is that it can take things out of context: for example, "I had to do something that work regulations insisted on" would count towards the 159,000, despite the word "work" not even being a verb here :-)

Answer (score 2):

3rd person singular verb should match the 3rd person singular noun.

- He/she/it works.
- He/she/it who/which/that works.

Answer (score 2):

Lots of people type "your" when they mean "you're" but that doesn't mean it is a viable variant, just a common mistake.  Likewise "something that works" is the correct grammar here.

Answer (score -5):

The simple answer for this:  *Something* in this case, is singular.  This means that the verb should be plural, *works*.  If you were to switch it around and use *Some things*, you would then use the singular verb *work*.

Comment: I don't believe it's correct to say the form of the verb "works" is plural just because it has an "s" on the end. Better to say, "the verb should use the 3rd person singular", which I think is what you meant.

Comment: Woah... 'singular verb'? Please show me where such a term is defined.

Comment: If by "plural" you mean that the verb is used for first, second, and third plural person, then you should be the opposite: _works_ is used only for the third singular person. _Work_ is then used for, e.g., _I work_, _you work_, and _we work_; you say that _work_ is a "singular verb", but it is used also for a plural person. _Singular verb_ and _plural verb_ are not expressions used in English.

Comment: You have to pay some more effort to make a better participation.